# SCSF custom Dependency Injection

Tags: unity-container, prism, cab, smartclient, scsf

I'd like to enhance/mimic the dependency injection done by the object builder to include some custom properties

the standard way is

in mySmartPart.cs

[CreateNew]
  MyPresenter ABC
  {
 ....
  }

[ServiceDependency]
  myService  XYZ
  {
 ...
  }

in include
   [MyCustomReferenceAttribute]
   CustomerObject  MyCustomer
   {
 ....
   }

etc.

This can obviously be done after the smartPart is created but i'm guessing ( hoping ? ) there's some place i can hook up some code extension to do the needful instead of repeating the code everyplace !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity/ObjectBuilder uses a chain of responsibility pattern called its Strategy Chain.  You can plugin your own steps in this chain to get some customization out of how Unity/ObjectBuilder does its object construction.

Here's more information about the design of Unity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440939.aspx

My gut says that you are really wanting to replace large parts of Unity.  I think this would require you to gut large parts of this strategy chain and replace it with customized versions.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, it is *possible* that simply inheriting your attributes from [DependencyResolutionAttribute](http://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/39621#427223) and just *add* a strategy to the StrategyChain.  Here's how the default strategies are configured (and also a complete list of strategies in use in Unity: http://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/39621#427281

I know this is a lot of information, but hopefully this gives you a few directions.